# Best practice for getting location from firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app I want to get nearby users from database, in my firebase database I have User objects which have `lat` and `long` fields, also I have a `timestamp` field and retrieve active users by `timestamp` then filtering location in OS.I know that I can't make a query filtering both `lat` and `long`, but is there any way to get nearby users with just one `integer` or maybe there is a lib for that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can** actually filter by lat and long by using [GeoFire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire), a library that uses GeoHashes to merge lat+lon into a single property.

That way you can do the distance filtering directly on the database, and do the time-based filtering in code, or by only having the Geo-location in the database for the users whose timestamp is within your filter range.